# Let a: N → R be a sequence with a (n) → A ∈ R as n → ∞. Find B ∈ R such that for b: N → R with b (n): =. $\frac{1}{n}\sum_k^n$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, proof-writing

I am having trouble with a problem for 3 days.
I am having a problem understanding this one. To be honestly, I don't know the first step to take to solve it. I solve the other problems like this using the sandwich theorem but for this one I can't even understand.
Let a: N → R be a sequence with a (n) →  A ∈ R as n → ∞.. Find B ∈ R such that for b: N → R with b (n): =. $\frac{1}{n}\sum_k^n$. k=1
for all n ∈ N ∗ and b (0) ∈ R arbitrarily we have $b(n)\to_{n\to\infty}B$.

To better see the math terms (the problem is in Germany)
[problem is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfB40.jpg)

Thank you

Comment: What does "$a_n\to n$" mean???

Comment: And what do $n\to\infty A$ and $n\to\infty B$ mean???

Comment: "$\frac{1}{n}\sum_k^n$. k=1" ???

Comment: it means that the k under n ist equal 1,m but I couldn't write it on

Comment: do you mean to say $a_n\to A\in\mathbb{R}$ as $n\to\infty$? I'm having trouble trying to interpret what your $b_n$ is supposed to be, the sum doesn't even have a general term. If this was the problem statement as written, I too would have trouble for days trying to solve this.

Comment: Yes. an→A∈R  as n→∞. That's what I mean

Comment: what is the general term in the sum supposed to be, i.e., the sequence $b_n$?

Comment: b(n) is the sequence

Comment: @CSquared I added a picture of the given problem. You can better see the math symbol there

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I added an image of the problem. The problem is written in german

Comment: Ok. The definition of $b(n)$ should be `\frac 1 n\sum_{k=1}^n a(k)` .

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, yes, You are right. Sorry, my bad...

Comment: so fix it......

Answer (score 1):

We have that $b_n \to A$ as $n \to \infty$. Indeed, let $\epsilon>0$. There exists $N_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n-A|<\epsilon/3$ for all $n \geq N_1$.

Let $$\alpha=\sum_{k=1}^{N_1-1}a_k$$

Let $N_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ be such that $|\alpha/N_2|<\epsilon/3$ for all $n \geq N_2$. Finally, let $N_3 \in \mathbb{N}$ be such that $|(N_1-1)A/N_3| < \epsilon/3$ for all $n \geq N_3$. Let $N=\max\{N_1,N_2,N_3\}$. For all $n \geq N$,

$$|(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k)-A| \leq |\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{N_1-1} a_k|+|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{N_1-1}A|+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=N_1}^n|a_k-A|<\epsilon/3+\epsilon/3+\epsilon/3=\epsilon.     $$